# Codeigniter Active Record inside custom library class

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter

My function breaks at the line where I make an Active Record call, so I must not be calling things right.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Stuff {
    public function specific($passedArray) {

         echo "Test";

            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->load->database();
            $CI->load->helper('array');
            $CI->load->helper('format_helper');

            $dataArray = $this->db->where($column_name, $StockNum);
            $dataArray = $this->db->get($tablename);

            echo "Bollocks!";
```

"Test" will echo, but not Bollocks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using $CI->db->... not $this->db

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
$db = $CI->load->database();
$dataArray = $db->where($column_name, $StockNum);
$dataArray = $db->get($tablename);
```